# Starting screensaver from terminal

Tags: command-line, centos, screensaver

I like the 'Black Screen' screen-saver. Because it makes the monitor look like turned-off. But my CentOS takes minimum 1 min. to start it automatically.

Can I start it instantly from the terminal?

I sometimes need this feature while working with 2 monitors with two different OS. CentOS is on my VNC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On modern distros you'd do `xdg-screensaver activate`

Comment: This solution working on my `Ubuntu 20.04`

Answer (score 13):

If all you want to do is blank the screen, as opposed to running a fancy animation or locking the screen, then [`xset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xset) can do it.

```
xset dpms force off
```

If you want to lock the display, you need a screen locking program, e.g. `xscreensaver-command -lock -activate` or `gnome-screensaver -al` or (for KDE4) `qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock`.

If you want to turn off one monitor only, you can to it through [`xrandr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xset) (unless you're using a proprietary display driver, in which case you'll have the tools provided by NVidia/ATI).

```
xrandr --output DVI1 --off
```

This won't be undone by moving the mouse, you need to run `xrandr --output DVI1 --auto` to bring the monitor back.

Comment: That was awesome :) . I didn't knew about that .

Comment: But if you're concerned about security (and you should be) then you should use `xlock` or `xscreensaver` before turning off the display. (Perhaps make a wrapper that does both.)

Comment: @bahamat For the use case “working with 2 monitors with two different OS”, locking doesn't seem useful, but I've edited it in anyway.

Comment: @Gilles: I've got to try it. But the worstation is at my office and  I use windows when I'm home.I have to wait this weekend :(       .Thanks ... and I'm sorry for being late.

Comment: @Gilles: Hi , Gilles... It gives this message : server does not have extension for dpms option xset: unknown option force '

Answer (score 9):

You can use `xscreensaver-command`:

```
$ xscreensaver-command -activate
```

or, with XScreenSaver 6 or later:

```
$ xscreensaver-command --activate
```

If it is not there on your system, on Debian derivatives you can install it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xscreensaver
```

On Fedora/CentOS/RHEL you install it with this command:

```
$ sudo yum install xscreensaver-base
```

Comment: If you use gnome, you can use `gnome-screensaver-command --activate`. No need to install `xscreensaver`.

Comment: When I tried using `gnome-screensaver-command --activate` my screen got locked instead of the activation of screensaver .I am using Linux Mint 14 Nadia.Do you have any idea why is it so ?

Comment: Hey Tushar Makkar , it shows 'apt-get: command not found' !!

Comment: Hi , for centOS/RHEL you need to use `yum install "package name"` that is in this case use `su -c "yum install xscreensaver"` to install Xscreensaver . For Debian based linux we use `apt-get`.

Comment: But , it displays : 'No package **xscreensaver** available.Error: Nothing to do'

Comment: Did you try using  `sudo yum install xscreensaver-base` ?

Comment: I did it with the root user...

Comment: I meant did u use `xscreensaver-base` ?  Anyways you can download the rpm from this [link](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=xscreensaver) and install xscreensaver .

Comment: You can see my [screen](http://ctrlv.in/201121) :

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9223/discussion-between-tushar-makkar-and-md-mohiuddin-ahmed)

Comment: @andcoz: It just displays : '** Message: Screensaver is not running!'

Comment: Initially when you type the command it asks whether you want to run the screensaver in background ? You need to select yes and select the screensavers from the given list.

Comment: @TusharMakkar: but it's not asking anything.... just the message.

Answer (score 0):

Per the other answer, I use:

```
xscreensaver-command -a
```

On Arch/Manjaro, I installed it from the AUR using:

```
$ yay -S xscreensaver
```